# Apache: Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: apache

I'm really frustrated, my apache server doesn't start, my error.log is this:

```
[Fri Jul 26 16:26:20.211050 2013] [core:notice] [pid 32240:tid 268] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\users\\mrvisiont\\desktop\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/MrViSiOnT/Desktop/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jul 26 16:26:20.213050 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32240:tid 268] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 32112
[Fri Jul 26 16:26:20.225050 2013] [:crit] [pid 32112] (-2146173818)Unknown error: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
[Fri Jul 26 16:26:20.227051 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 32240:tid 268] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

I don't know what is the meaning of "Could not initialize random number generator"

Anybody knows what is the issue????

EDIT:

When I run httpd.exe, error.log is:

```
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [notice] Digest: done
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 16760
    no listening sockets available, shutting down
    Unable to open logs
    [Fri Jul 26 16:52:31 2013] [crit] (OS 87)El parámetro no es correcto.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

EDIT (FYI): Thank you people!
    When I comment ServerName line from httpd.conf... error.log is:

```
    httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::8e3:cc40:2151:c412 for ServerName
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:11 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:11 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:12 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:12 2013] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:12 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 13816
httpd.exe: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MRVISIONT-PC
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[Fri Jul 26 17:03:12 2013] [crit] (OS 6)Controlador no válido.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Comment: I had this problem and posted a solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323305/apache-commands-failing-with-ah00141-could-not-initialize-random-number-genera

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and troubleshooted for days before I finally stumbled upon the solution:

Ensure that your system's `PATH` environment variable does not contain illegal characters such as "b?????Ä/????????".

Removing such entries resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

```
[:crit] [pid 7368] (-2146173818)Unknown error: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
```

I checked the system's PATH environment variable and found Chinese signs in it.
Since I deleted them, Apache works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment settings. There may be an invalid character in it. See http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=5535

Besides that: it looks like you are missing the logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today for a completely different reason:  No PATH environment variable (at all).

The environment variable hint put me on the right track.  Dumping environment vars via a test application instead of starting Apache revealed the underlying issue.  The Windows `CreateProcess()` API is generally [difficult to work with](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/createprocess-windows).