# Apache shutdown unexpectedly (changing ports not worked)

Tags: apache, iis, xampp, shutdown

Xampp not runs apache,
**IIS not installed on my system** **(windows 8.1)** and **ports 80 and 443 are free**, tried to change ports to **45554** and **4430** but error exists! any idea?

```
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
7:04:00 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums


[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.000861 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 36732:tid 380] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.000861 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 36732:tid 380] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.000861 2013] [core:notice] [pid 36732:tid 380] AH00094: Command line: 'f:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d F:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.001861 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 36732:tid 380] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 33376
[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.009866 2013] [:crit] [pid 33376] (-2146173795)Unknown error: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
[Sun Nov 24 19:04:00.012867 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 36732:tid 380] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error is 'Could not initialize random number generator'
see this thread:
[Apache: Could not initialize random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884176/apache-could-not-initialize-random-number-generator)

Comment: I set that variable now, restart system, not works! :/
error still there!
PATH variable:
F:\xampp\php;F:\xampp\mysql\bin;F:\xampp\apache;

Comment: That is a curiously short path variable value. Are you sure you set the system path variable, not the user path variable?

Comment: oh! I think I set the user PATH :D

Comment: Yes, you have modified the path variable for your session. You need to  set the system path variable as that is the one read by services and all users.