# xamp error apache dont want start no matter what

Tags: php, apache, xampp

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.009909 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.033911 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH00455: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.033911 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Oct 22 2017 11:52:30
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.033911 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.034911 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 544
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.046911 2017] [:crit] [pid 544] (-2146173818)Unknown error: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
[Fri Nov 17 22:05:26.048911 2017] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 6880:tid 288] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

- I tried skype not working kill process skype also
- I changed port to like 10 different ports not working
- I don't have IIS
- I tried to run the batch file via cmd
- I did try reinstall clean install nothing change

Whatever I do I am getting same error.

Comment: Did you take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884176/apache-could-not-initialize-random-number-generator ?

Comment: Yes thanks for post i tried also check my Path but there was no weird symbols in my path

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED , i reinstall xampp so many times that I had like x6 allowed apache and mysql in the windows firewall. I removed them all did a clean install and now all works like charm !